# Convert char array and return as a String

Tags: java, string, char, return, reverse

I try to create a method, which get as parameter a String. This String will be splitted and every word will be reversed(without special characters).

I need to make this method returnable and when I tried to realize it, I got just last word of string which I gave as input parameter.

Would you have any ideas, how could I solve this problem?

```
public String reverse(String inputString) {
    for(String word : inputString.split(" ")){
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = letters.length - 1;

        while(leftIndex < rightIndex){
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(letters[leftIndex]))
                leftIndex++;
            else if(!Character.isAlphabetic(letters[rightIndex]))
                rightIndex--;
            else
            {
                char temp = letters[leftIndex];
                letters[leftIndex] = letters[rightIndex];
                letters[rightIndex] = temp;
                leftIndex++;
                rightIndex--;
            }
        }
        inputString = String.valueOf(letters);
    }
    return inputString;
}
```

Comment: `inputString = String.valueOf(letters);` - you are overwriting the value of `inputString` in every iteration of the loop.  Create a new variable `String [] returnValues` to store the reversed Strings.  You want to return `String[]` not `String`

Comment: since your String is overwritten, you can create a list at the beginning of your method - `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`
then add elements to it, and finally return `list.toString();`

Comment: `String result = "";` and at end of loop `result += String.valueOf(letters) + " ";` (basic idea, can/should be improved - e.g. reversing directly into the result)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to reverse a String. So to reverse a String there is a built in method in Java. You can use the `reverse()` method of `StringBuilder` class.
For example:-

```
public String reverse(String input){  

    String words[]=input.split(" ");

    String output="";  

    for(String str:words){  

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(str);  
        sb.reverse();  
        output += sb.toString()+" ";  
    }  
    return output.trim(); // removes whitespace at the end
}
```